# IntelliJ IDEA Testing - How to display branch coverage

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, jacoco

In Eclipse with jacoco, I can get branch coverage percentage.

[image]

But in IntelliJ IDEA, I can only get lines&method coverage percentage in coverage window.

[image]

How to summarize branch coverage in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102075

Answer (score 9):

In IntelliJ to add "branch coverage" to the coverage window, you can go to Run/EditConfiguration then proceed to Modify options/coverage setting and enable use tracing.

Here is an example
[image: branch coverage example]

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: In the newer IDE versions, the option seems to have changed, it's now known as "Enable branch coverage and test tracking"

Answer (score 8):

First, by default intellij **not** showing **the branch coverage** inside `Coverage` window.
*Personally, I think it is better to show it by default.*

So if you are interested in "branch coverage", you need to **activate its config** `Use tracing`.

You have 2 options:

1. Set the config "Globbaly" for all tests:

- You can change the **template** of RUN/DEBUG config by follow the below steps:

[image]

2. Set the config "Custom" for one test RUN/DEBUG config:

- You can change the **cutom** of RUN/DEBUG config for a partuiclar test by follow the below ste:

[image]